# Android Spinner using Array with IDs to Image Resources

Tags: android, image, spinner, adapter

Okay here it goes, I am trying to make a custom spinner, using only images. I have an array defined on .xml file at values folder where there are the image items as resources..
I want to fill a spinner with this images..
Here is everything I done till now:

at res/drawable-mdpi

I have the following images:

remove_minus_circle_black.png 
remove_minus_circle_red.png 
remove_minus_sign.png
remove_minus_sign2.png
remove_minus_sign3.png

at res/values/arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="minusIcons">
       <item>@drawable/remove_minus_circle_black</item>
       <item>@drawable/remove_minus_circle_red</item>
       <item>@drawable/remove_minus_sign</item>
       <item>@drawable/remove_minus_sign2</item>
       <item>@drawable/remove_minus_sign3</item>

   </array>

    <array name="directionIcons">

   </array>

</resources>
```

at res/layout/row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Now the code (the activity itself) where I am trying to add the images to the spinner using a custom adapter:

```
public class Definicoes extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_definicoes);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.minusSpinner);

        int[] array = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.minusIcons);
        String [] objects = new String[array.length];
        for(int i = 0; i != array.length; i++){
            objects[i] = "" + array[i];
        }

        spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(Definicoes.this, R.id.minusSpinner, objects)); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.definicoes, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        String[] objects;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);


            ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(objects[position]));

            return row;
         }
     }


}
```

The problem/bug : I open the activity, then I click on the spinner and its nothing there!
Thanks alot in advance guys! I guess I might doing something wrong, never worked with custom adapters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution using this:

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.minusIcons);
icon.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(position, -1));
```

And changing the type of array to string-array, it worked :P